# Redirect from a "shortcut site" to a full site preserving an argument

Tags: apache

I've got a bunch of QR code labels encoded with URL's like "https://mysh.ort.url/A5B6D", and I need to redirect them to "https://www.myfullsite.com/items/item.php?A5B6D".

I tried with:
 RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/ https://www.myfullsite.com/items/item.php?$1
 [R,L]

But it doesn't work. I'm not too strong with regexes but all the "item codes" I've tried don't seem to work. They are all 5 characters and only letters or uppercase numbers. I managed to make it work with a blanket redirect, but I want to preserve other format URL's on the shorthand domain for other purposes, so ideally it should only redirect requests that are only 5 letters or numbers after the /, like "https://mysh.ort.url/A1BCD" but not "https://mysh.ort.url/gimme/news".

Comment: In the real host configuration file (/etc/apache2/hosts-available/myshorthandsite.conf) - there's another section there that rewrites http URL's to https, and that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that rule placed in the real host configuration or a cheap .htaccess style file?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ https://www.fullsite.com/items/item.php?$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would be a more precise version:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Z0-9]{5})$ https://www.fullsite.com/items/item.php?$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note the `?` following the leading slash (`/`). You have to consider the different bases RewriteRules work on in the real host configuration and `.htaccess` style files. Absolute versus relative. Also You have to remove the trailing slash from your pattern.

I also added the `=301` parameter to the redirection flag, since most likely you want an external redirect, not an internal one.

In general one should prefer to place such rules inside the host configuration of the http server *whenever possible*. More transparent, more reliable, more efficient. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prine, hard to debug and they *really* slow down the server, often for nothing. They are only provided as a last fallback for users without access to the host configuration, so for example in situations with a really cheap web hosting provider.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but the rewrite rule still doesn't get acted on. Here's the full section:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ==on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ https://www.myfullsite.com/items/item.php?$1 [R,L]

Comment: Then please enable rewrite loggin and check the details in your http servers log files. Most likely not an issue with the rule itself, but the situation or the request. Sure you placed the rule inside the correct host definition? :-)